# Jenkins cucumber not serving static files

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, directory-browsing

our jenkins can serve this:
http://jenkins:8000/view/all/job/my-cucumber/273/cucumber-living-documentation/

but returns a http 404 when trying to switch styles and effectively calling this:

http://jenkins:8000/view/all/job/my-cucumber/273/cucumber-living-documentation/themes/github.css

How to make jenkins to serve this url?

All googles point to CSP which has nothing to do with it.
CSP is a header that says what a browser shall safely request on the page served.

But I want to know how to enable jenkins to allow directory browsing.

Answer (score 0):

please update to version 2.2.1 of cucumber living documentation plugin, it fixed the issue with theme switching and also it doesn't need CSP header anymore. See changelog here: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Cucumber+Living+Documentation+Plugin#CucumberLivingDocumentationPlugin-ChangeLog